# PostgreSQL / TimescaleDB query that group data by custom interval

Tags: postgresql, group-by, timescaledb, dateinterval

I have a working query that allows me to sum `value` field each day.

```
SELECT sum(value) as sum_value, to_char(time::date,'DD-MM-YY') as day 
FROM "measures"  
GROUP BY "day" 
ORDER BY "day" asc
```

Is it possible to do the same query, but instead of grouping by day, grouping it by 2 days,or a specific duration ( days only, not hours)

Comment: Use `time_bucket()` https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/reading-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timescaledb` extension `time_bucket()` function as  @Mike Organek commented or use native `PosgreSQL` data transformation like:

```
SELECT 
    sum(value) as sum_value, 
    to_char(time::date,'DD-MM-YY') as day,
    floor(extract(epoch from "time")/(60*60*24*2)) as time_bucket
FROM "measures"  
GROUP BY "time_bucket" 
ORDER BY "day" asc;
```

In above query we extract unixtime from datetime column, divide it to grouping period in seconds (60*60*24*2 - mean 2 days or 48 hours) and round it fro use into group by statement

Comment: In general, would recommend using time_bucket when possible.  It does what you want, and some planning optimizations and other capabilities will work well with `time_bucket` but not some of the other approaches as detailed.

(Timescale person here)